# In Lotus Notes 9 How do you manually run rules you've written on your inbox, without installing any other plugins / software?

Tags: email, lotus-notes, email-client, email-filter

It makes it very difficult to test the rules I have if only messages coming in can be matched when I run send and receive emails.  Is there a way to manually run them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Is there a way to manually run them [rules]?

Yes.

> Use the Enable Run Rules On Existing Mail setting in a Mail Settings
>   policy to enable users to run mail rules on messages that are already
>   stored in folders. To use this feature, users must use a mail file
>   that is upgraded to the Mail9.ntf template that is provided with 9.0.1
>   Feature Pack 9.

Source [IBM Can IBM Lotus Notes mail rules run on existing emails? - United States](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21987231)

Comment: Link to IBM source is broken

Comment: {shrug} the essential information is in the question as it should be.

Comment: Suppose all of this is enabled. Then what? How do you actually do it?